# Angularjs document,location.href And goBack

Tags: angularjs, history, back

I have problem using angularjs project.

why can't move "window.history.back();"

## 1 PAGE

```
   <button ng-click="link();">LINK</button>

   # Angular Code
   $scope.link = function(){
    document.location.href="#passwordChange"
   }
```

That linkbutton click movepage passwordChange.

but passwordChange page can't move backbutton

## Another Page

```
   <button ng-click="goBack();">Back</button>

   #Angular code
    $scope.goBack = function() {
      window.history.back();
    };
```

Some body help~ please

Comment: How you are handling routing in AngularJS and which Angular version you are using.

Comment: Angularjs produces a single page application. So window.history.back() makes no sense for that.